# Circuit for controlling AC signal polarity in real-time

Tags: arduino, signal, h-bridge, polarity

I'm going to start a project on a controlling speaker array and I need to control the signal's polarity fed into each speaker. I want to make a 'router' or 'controller' to make it easy, so I don't have to change all the wiring when I want to change the polarity distribution.

I googled some keywords and found H-bridge IC. But I'm not sure if that is compatible with AC signal. Besides, I'm afraid of controller size, because I need the controller for speaker ARRAY including many speakers, at least 9.

So, anyone who has an idea how can I solve the problem would be appreciated, very much. Now I'm thinking about kind of multi-channel connector that I can assign the signal to each port. (e.g., (+) signal to 1,3 port and (-) signal to 2,4 port)

Thanks for reading, I'm waiting for the advice. Have a nice day!

Comment: H bridges are for DC corrent. It is not clear what you want to achieve. What about a small graph with waiveforms you have and you want to feed to the speaker ?

Comment: @matzeri Thanks for a reply. I'm going to feed just sinusoidal signals to each speaker, but with different polarity(out-of-phase). So that they form a spatial distribution. Most simple case is dipole speaker, which has two speakers playing same signal, out-of-phase. I wanna extend this concept into 2-D array.

Comment: This could work if you only need to change the signals sometimes.  You will have to modify slightly to power the relay from a separate supply but it will let you have just one relay per speaker to set and REMEMBER the polarity.  -  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146258/change-direction-of-12v-dc-motor-rotation-using-relay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a DPDT switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX0yRx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you want to control this from a remote panel, you can use DPDT relays to do that.