# High voltage polarity inverter circuit

Tags: high-voltage, flyback, reverse-polarity, polarity

I'm building a cloud chamber which needs to use an high voltage source. I'm using an electric fly swatter circuit which can generate about 4kV. The fact is that I want to use a button to switch the polarity of the output of this circuit. In the cloud chamber there are two metal peices to which I've connected the output terminals of the HV circuit, this creates an electric field, so that electrons are repelled or attracted to the metal plate which is placed inside the active region of the chamber (that is the region in which particle can be seen) . I've tried to search online for some circuits that can invert singnals polarity: some designs which I like use a 555 timer like this one:

[image]

The fact is that 4kV is a very high voltage to handle, and I have no idea on how to adapt it to the mentioned circuit.

I include a schematic of the fly swatter circuit, which, I think, Is something like this (I've already modified It a bit by shorting the push button with a tri-state button, so that the generator can stay on for long periods of time:

[image]

So, is there a way to add a polarity inverter circuit on the output of the electric fly swatter circuit? Or, if not, how could I modify the fly swatter circuit itself to add this feature?

Thank you in advance for your answers, and excuse my english: I'm still practising it!

Comment: This isn't very clear: *reversing polarity means that eletrons are seen more easily than positrons, or viceversa*

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to clarify things.

Comment: How fast do you want to invert the polarity? The easiest way would be to use a non-polarised plug and socket between swatter and chamber, so you can plug it in either way round. I would suggest a reversing relay, but you'd need a specialised high voltage one to withstand 4 kV.

Comment: Why does it make a difference what the polarity is; the way you have described the cloud chamber appears to be symmetrical. Maybe you should make a diagram. Maybe just use HV AC so that polarity is alternating. That's a lot simpler than trying to invert HV DC connections. Possible XY problem? Or, just repurpose a car distributor.

Comment: The cloud chamber is not symmetrical: this two plates are placed one on the other with a distance of 15cm. The upper region has a temperature of about 30°C, the lower one of -30°C. Particle can be seen only over the plate at -30°C. AC is not as effective since it alternates continously and I have no means to control when the switching occurs: it is periodical...

Comment: @Neil_UK I though that maybe it could be simpler if there was a way to modify the HV circuit itself such that, depending on the polarity with which the supply is connected, the output has a different polarity, this way the reversing polarity circuit has to deal with 3V which is much simpler. But the HV circuit is not symmetrical... So I have no idea

Comment: @Luke__ so do you want to reverse the polarity at a precise time during the measurement, or do you want to do a run at one polarity, then a run at the other polarity? 4 kV makes electronic solutions non-trivial. A mechanical solution is simple, if you can tolerate the manual intervention and the low reversing speed.

Comment: The idea was to reverse the polarity during the same measurement, but if you say so, i think I can adapt to the mechanical on. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest: use relays.  See: [Change Direction of 12v DC Motor Rotation using Relay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146258/change-direction-of-12v-dc-motor-rotation-using-relay)

For high voltages, you will need specialty relays, which will be expensive.  But it is the most straightforward solution.

Purely electronic methods are significantly more complex: either the equivalent circuit with transistors (many in series to handle the high voltage, preferably with protective circuitry to handle the inevitable spark discharge), or use two power supplies, wired such that one or the other can be powered to set the output polarity.

An equivalent solution might be building a relay by hand, using bits of wire, foil, plastic, etc.  Your application needs very little current handling, as I understand it.  But the design of such is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that the option involving two power supplies seems the more feesable to me, since I'm using a computer PSU. Just one perplexity; it is possible to power the HV circuit with reverse polarity to obtain an output with inverted polarity?.

Comment: No, that will blow it up.