# How to control the speed of a DC motor that can rotate in both directions?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

This is my case:
My cargo van has fan/extractor powered by an one-speed brushed 12v motor.
Two switches in the instrument panel control the rotation of the motor by reversing the polarity.
Switch 1: makes the motor spin in FAN direction.
Switch 2: reverses the polarity and rotate in the other direction for EXTRACTOR.

I need to regulate the speed on both directions and the "device" is to be mounted in the roof of the van in the best (protected) manner possible.

I got a cheap controller that works fine until the polarity is reversed, then the extractor moves at a constant-very-low speed.

Any suggestions (for a simple-as-possible) will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Direction of 12v DC Motor Rotation using Relay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146258/change-direction-of-12v-dc-motor-rotation-using-relay)

Comment: @winny That post is about changing the direction of a motor, the question is how to change the speed of the motor.

Comment: @GodJihyo OP said he already have a controller. He can use that and polarity switch the motor with a DPDT relay.

Comment: @winny The way I read it is they have a main power switch and a reversing switch already working, now they want to add speed control. Since they mention mounting a 'device' in the roof of the van I'm thinking they've put the speed controller up there with the fan so that it's after the reversing switch.

Comment: @GodJihyo I see your point. It's certainly up for interpretation. Non the less, your answer below should be what OP is after.

Comment: almost any hbridge circuit or module should do that just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The switch should just be reversing the wires to the motor. What it sounds like you've done is to put the speed controller after the switch. This would cause the voltage input to the controller to be reversed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkoyS5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If this is what you've done (you didn't provide any diagrams) then you should move the controller before the reversing switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu6Ljo.png)</sup>